# Opening a file which is being used by someone else in another machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

My task is to generate Word documents. By selecting the appropriate options, we can generate a document.  I have the base documents in the server, and if I click generate, then the document will be generated and we can save it on our local drive.

If I am using the portal now and, at the same time, if some one is using it in their machine at the same time, then the document is not getting generated.  It's automatically getting posted back.

I want to show a progress bar or something like that, so that the person waits until the document is completely generated.

Is this possible using threads?

Comment: If the problem is that the server is using a single name for the document, then why not use a unique name per client session?

Comment: Hi Greg.. The name is unique in the base document. and in the generated document, the name appears with date,empId of the person who is opening, time with secs and base doc name.. So i don think the name is a problem here.

Comment: @GregHewgill I believe the problem is that the server will generate it on the fileserver, but people click the link _before_ generation is completed. ICBWT

Comment: This is the code i have used to read.
using (Stream tplStream = File.OpenRead(templatePath))
            {
                documentStream = new MemoryStream((int)tplStream.Length);
                CopyStream(tplStream, documentStream);
                documentStream.Position = 0L;
            }

Answer (score 0):

When you read your base document on the server, use [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s67691sb.aspx) with [FileAccess.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) or [File.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx).
By doing this, you can read the same files with several threads at the same time.

Comment: This is the code i have used to read. using (Stream tplStream = File.OpenRead(templatePath)) { documentStream = new MemoryStream((int)tplStream.Length); CopyStream(tplStream, documentStream); documentStream.Position = 0L; }

Comment: Ok, so the problem is not that. Do you have an error when you generates two documents at the same time?

Comment: Yes, The error is recorded in Log which says like "the file is opened by XXX and cannot be used now".. but if i click generate after few mins, i am able to generate..

Comment: What do you do in CopyStream ?
Because with OpenRead the base document can beread by several threads.
The documentStream is saved in a file with a unique name?
And why do you copy the stream? You can just copy the file and edit the copy which have a unique name.

Comment: public void UpdateTOC(string file1, string file2) { using (var mainDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file1, false)) using (var resultDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(file2, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) { // copy parts from source document to new document foreach (var part in mainDoc.Parts) resultDoc.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId); // perform replacements in resultDoc.MainDocumentPart // ... } } }
This is the code i have used for copying the main doc and the result doc.. pls have a look at it.

Comment: I don't see the link between the last portion of code and this one... Anyway, just verify that at each step of your code the file can be opened by another process. From where file2 comes? Is it the same filename for every copy?